# How to Filter Data with Multiple Parameters

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'd like to tally a series of data based on the day and user name. The data is being fed from a query, and I am not looking to use a pivot table because I would like to archive the data past what the program I am pulling the data from stores. Below is a sample of the data I have collected.

[image]

I want to tally the Column D "FULL_PLLT_QTY", but only for the date in Column G "SHIFT_DT" and the Column I "Name".

EX. I want to tally Column D for 6/7/2107 for Smith, R.W.

Is there a way to do this for a large range of dates and names? Also, the names appear on multiple dates. Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: did you try a Pivot table?

Comment: @ScottCraner I have a pivot table, already, but my goal is to archive this data, because it is coming in from a query, and I have found it difficult to archive query data.

Comment: If the data is formatted as an Excel Table, you may insert Slicers for the target columns and select the slicer items to filter the table.

Comment: @sktneer It doesn't seem like I'm able to do that since it's not in pivot table format.

Comment: Slicers can also be inserted on Excel Table apart from Pivot Tables. Convert your data into an Excel Table format by clicking inside the data and press Ctrl+T and check the checkbox for "My table has headers" and then go to Table design and there you will find a button called Insert Slicer.

Comment: @sktneer I tried that, but the problem is I don't want to do this for every single person for every single day. I'm looking at like 6000 data points.

Comment: Then you may try Advanced Filter and copy the filtered data onto another sheet or just filter the list in place. Record a macro using Advanced Filter, modify it and reuse it when required.

Answer (score 0):

`=SUMIFS(D:D,G:G,"6/7/2017 0:00",I:I,"Smith, R.W.")`

Matching the date condition will depend on the exact format of column G. The above assumes it is just a string. If ti is a date then you probably need to use `=DATE(2017,7,6)` instead of the literal string "6/7/2017 0:00".

Comment: I'm not sure this is what I'm looking for. I am trying to look at like 10,000 data points, and doing that for each day for 40 people wouldn't work. I'm looking for something that will sum the data for each day and name automatically.

Comment: Then make a list of all the names, add columns for all the dates, then fill in that matrix with a parameterised version of the formula I suggested. Suppose names in col X and dates in row 1. Then put this formula in cell Y2: `=SUMIFS(D:D,G:G,Y$1,I:I,$X2)`. Drag that formaula throughout the matrix.

Comment: To get the initial list of names, copy your existing col I, paste it somewhere, and use Data > Remove Duplicates.